# S3 Direct Upload - Several Issues Uploading a File

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I am using the Rails s3_direct_upload gem to enable my Heroku app to upload a file directly from the users browser, but I'm having some difficulty getting it working. There are three problems I'm seeing.

1. When uploading, the correct folders are created in the S3 bucket, but no file appears there.
2. The upload returns to an XML PostResponse page instead of the specified controller action.
3. I have set the multiple files flag to false, but I can keep adding files in the upload form.

It's taken a while to get to this stage, I initially had a lot of trouble just getting past an error return from Amazon but fixed that by including         the "hidden_field_tag 'Content-type', ''" tag.

Initialiser: config/s3_direct_upload.rb

```
S3DirectUpload.config do |c|
    c.access_key_id = <KEY>
    c.secret_access_key = <SECKEY>
    c.bucket = 'bucket'
    c.region = 's3-ap-southeast-2'
    c.url = nil
end
```

Javascript: application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require fuelux.min
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require moment
//= require daterangepicker
//= require meiomask
//= require s3_direct_upload

...

$(function() {
    $("#s3-uploader").S3Uploader();
});
```

The code in the view:

```
<div class="transaction_area">
    <%= s3_uploader_form callback_url: {:controller => 'sales', :action => 'upcreate', :id => @organisation.id},
                     callback_param: 'model[image_url]',
                     key: "organisations/org_#{@organisation.id}/sales/${filename}",
                     key_starts_with: 'organisations/',
                     id: 's3-uploader' do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'Content-type', '' %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file, multiple: false %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Upload' %>
<% end %>

<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
    <div id="file-{%=o.unique_id%}" class="upload">
      {%=o.name%}
      <div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width: 0%"></div></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

It gives me this result:

```
<PostResponse>
    <Location>
         https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/bucket/organisations%2Forg_1%2Fsales%2F
    </Location>
    <Bucket>bucket</Bucket>
    <Key>organisations/org_1/sales/</Key>
    <ETag>"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"</ETag>
</PostResponse>
```

I think that I've done everything necessary, but could someone check this please and let me know what I've done wrong, or missed. Cheers.

**Update 1**

Okay. Made some progress. It turns out much of the problem was in my CORS config. I used the one specified in the document at https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload which is

```
<CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://0.0.0.0:3000</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

After changing the AllowedOrigin to

```
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
```

the upload now uploads the file to the correct folder in the S3 bucket. (I also previously changed the port to 3002 since that was the address the development server is running on, but that had no effect.  It was using the wildcard character that appears to have done the trick.)

It also no longer returns the PostResponse page, and when the file is selected it uploads automatically without waiting to add extra files and without the need to click the submit button (which I have removed.)

However, it's now not hitting the callback_url and in my logs I am seeing the error

```
ERROR bad URI `/organisation/1/sales/[object%20Object]'.
```

I've found a question on SO about this ([Bad URI Error using the s3_direct_upload gem (Javascript/RoR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648550/bad-uri-error-using-the-s3-direct-upload-gem-javascript-ror)) but it hasn't been answered. So I'm still at a bit of a loss.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: any solution you found?